# How to find amount of threads that are used to execute a job

Tags: quartz.net

I need to make only one thread execute my job. So after a little research I came to the following implementation:

```
var properties = new NameValueCollection { { "quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "1" } };
var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);

var scheduler = factory.GetScheduler();
```

Based on how my job works it seems like my task is still executed with several threads. May be I've configured it wrong...

What is the easiest way to find out in runtime how many threads Quartz.net uses to execute a job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way may be setting up your own [IJobListener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html)

Register it like this to track only the job you are interested in:

```
    var myJobListener = new JobListener();
    scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(myJobListener, KeyMatcher<JobKey>.KeyEquals(new JobKey("myJobName", "myJobGroup")));
```

In your JobListener you will need to implement methods from the interface:

```
public void JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException)
{
      //in here you can keep track of the current thread:
      var threadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
}
```